# SQL Alchemy Check Connection

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I created the below method to connect to SQL Server using SQL Alchemy and Pyodbc.

```
def getDBEngine(server, database):
    Params = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+";TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes")
    Engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % Params)

    return Engine
```

I'm able to then use that engine to read and write data via methods like to_sql from pandas per the below.

```
def toSQL(Server, Database, Tablename):
    writeEngine= getDatabaseEngine(Server, Database)
    data.to_sql('write_Tablename',writeEngine,if_exists='append')
```

My question is whether there is a simple way to check the connection/ status of the engine before actually using it to read or write data.  What's the easiest way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One pattern I've seen used at multiple engagements is essentially a "is alive" check that is effectively `select 1 as is_alive;`. There's no data access, so it just checks where your connection is receptive to receiving commands from your application.

Comment: this will produce QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running in Qt-based program if there's no connection to the database